# jQuery dropdown dependent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdown lists. The first one shows the regions from a country, the other one every city in the selected state. The problem is that after I submit my form MySQL Database
gets from the first list the ID of the region selected, while the second list doesen't show anything. I want to make my database receive the right information. The name of the region and the name of the city.

*How can I do this?*

#### My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".region").change(function() {`enter code here`
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_city.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(".city").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

#### My `section.php` script is:

```
<?php

  <label>Country :</label> <select name="country" class="country">
  <option selected="selected">--Select Region--</option>

<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,region FROM regions ORDER BY region");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id     = $row['id'];
    $region = $row['region'];
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $region . '</option>';
  } 
?>
 </select> <br/><br/>
 <label>City :</label> <select name="city" class="city">
 <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>

 </select>

?>
```

#### The `ajax_city.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

if($_POST['id']) {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM CITY where id_city=$id order by city");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $id=$row['id'];
      $data=$row['city'];
      echo "<option value=$id>$data</option>";
    }
 }

?>
```

The code works fine. But I can't figure out what to do with the database. I think I have to change something in the JavaScript?

Any help please?

Comment: replace `$_POST['id']` with `$_POST['country']` in `ajax_city.php`, select tags value posts with key same as tag name attribute.

Comment: and change `$(".region")` to `$(".country")` , you don't have `.region` element in your html code

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".country").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val(); 
        var region = $(this).find('option:selected').html();  
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax_city.php",
          data: { country: id , name : region },
          cache: false,
          success: function(html)
           {
             $(".city").html(html);
             $(".city").removeAttr('disabled');
           } 
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

`section.php`

```
<label>Country :</label> 
<select name="country" class="country">
    <option selected="selected">--Select Region--</option>
        <?php
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,region FROM regions ORDER BY region");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
                $id=$row['id'];
                $region=$row['region'];
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$region.'</option>';
            } 
            ?>
</select><br/><br/>
<label>City :</label> 
<select disabled name="city" class="city">
    <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
```

`ajax_city.php`

```
<?php
    if($_POST['country'])
    {
        $id = $_POST['country'];
        $region = $_POST['name'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM CITY where id_city = $id order by city");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $data=$row['city'];
            echo "<option value=$id>$data</option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've replaced everithing you told me but now another problem showed up...now in my Form it doesn't display any of my cities when I select a region....I don't know if the javascript you wrote me is working... The thing is that..in my database  I have a Table called REGIONS an ID for every region (from 1 to 43, i think) and another TABLE  called CITY with id_city and city ...where all cities belonging to a specific region have the dame IDs with that region..Now..you told me to replace $_POST['id'] with $_POST['country'] ....but now it doesen]t seem to have any conection between the lists...

Comment: would you give your tables structure here?

Comment: i was thinking it could be useful ...to understand what i am trying to tell you... why replacing the $_POST['id'] with the $_POST['country']? ...How can this match the region index with the city index??...Should-t there be a connexion by ID's??

Comment: in script section i change code `data: dataString` to `data: { country: id }` and key is `country` and remove line `var dataString = 'id=' + id;`

Comment: i have mistake in the first comment I post to your question, in your first code `$_POST['id']` is correct

Comment: ok..now my code looks like this since i replaced $_POST['country'] with $_POST['id'] ....<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".country").change(function()
    {
    var id=$(this).val();   
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax_city.php",
          data: { id : id },
          cache: false,
          success: function(html)
           {
             $(".city").html(html);
             $(".city").removeAttr('disabled');
           } 
    });
    });
});
</script> but is still doese-nt send yhe right info to my database

Comment: are you get correct country id in `ajax_city.php` ?? in `ajax_city.php` text before if write ` echo "<option>$_POST['id']</option>" to check it

Comment: yes I've tested ..and it's returning me the right ID...but i haven't found a solution for returning to my Databese the right info...when I submit my form, my Databese recive the ID of the specific region...and the city recives nothing...empty...i know that the databese recives the value of the <option> and sice my value has the ID I don't know hot to make it take the name of the region ...apear in my database....also with my city column...witch is not reciving anuthing ..not even the id.. I don't wanna be a pain in the ass for all my questions..but i need to find a solution 10x

Comment: I solved the problem with the city...now si showing me the name of the city in my database...but  i still have to get the region name...not the ID...

Comment: do you want to get region name in `ajax_city.php` or when you submit form at final? if you want to get region name in `ajax_city.php` look again in codes, i edit codes to send region name to `ajax_city.php`

Answer (score 0):

Database: `country`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` ( `id_city` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id_city`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


INSERT INTO `city` (`id_city`, `city`, `pid`) VALUES(1, 'Gujarat', 1),(2, Maharashtra', 1),(3, 'Rajasthan', 1),(4, 'Madhya Pradesh', 1),(5, 'Lahore', 2),(6, 'hyderabad', 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regions` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `region` varchar(30) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `regions` (`id`, `region`) VALUES(1, 'India'),(2, 'Pakistan');
```

Javascript On default.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
 {
$(".country").change(function()
{
    var id=$(this).val(); 
    var region = $(this).find('option:selected').html();  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_city.php",
      data: { country: id , name : region },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
       {
         $(".city").html(html);
         $(".city").removeAttr('disabled');
       } 
   });
  });
 });
  </script>

 <label>Country :</label> 
 <select name="country" class="country">
  <option selected="selected">--Select Region--</option>
     <?php
            $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            $db=mysql_select_db("country",$conn);

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,region FROM regions ORDER BY region");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $region=$row['region'];
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$region.'</option>';
        } 
        ?>
   </select><br/><br/>
   <label>City :</label> 
  <select disabled name="city" class="city">
     <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
  </select>
```

ajax_city.php

```
<?php
  if($_POST['country'])
{
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("country",$conn);


    $id = $_POST['country'];
    $region = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM CITY where pid = $id order by city");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $data=$row['city'];
        echo "<option value=$id>$data</option>";
    }
}

?>
```