# dynamic drop down box from mysql

Tags: php, html

I got 3 input fields and each field are getting their data from its own tables called Tour type, country and destination respectively as shown

```
    <label>Tour Type</label>
    <select id="element_11" name="element_11" required> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
    <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
          $tour_type_id=$row['tour_type_id'];
          $name=$row['tour_name'];
          echo "<option value='$tour_type_id'>$name</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>



    <label>Country</label>
    <select id="element_12" name="element_12" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option> 
    <?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("Select countries_id,countries_name from countries");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
          $cid=$row['countries_id'];
          $name=$row['countries_name'];

          echo "<option value='$cid'>".$name."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>


    <label>Destination</label>
    <select id="element_13" name="element_13" required> 
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    <?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("Select destination_id,destination_name from destination");


        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
          $destination_id=$row['destination_id'];
          $name=$row['destination_name'];

          echo "<option value='$destination_id'>".$name."</option>";
        }
        ?>

    </select>
    </div> 
    </li>
```

This is what i got as my 3 database tables i.e. tourtype, countries and destination respectively:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make each field dependent on each other more like a dependent drop down box. For example if i select a tour type then the 2nd drop down should populate options only relevant to what is selected from the 1st drop down and so on. In this case for e.g if i select culture ,then the 2nd drop down should only show amsterdam and belgium.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: $ AJAX will do for you.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449547/jquery-dropdown-dependent

Comment: 1) If there is not much data and the amount of users is low, you can select all data, build all the select fields as required and show/hide them as needed. Not recommended tho! 2) AJAX: Select only specific data with ajax and rebuild select element according to data received. For fastest and development time I recommend you to use jQuery for ajax queries and DOM manipulation.

Comment: Sorry i have never used ajax before and do not know how to put it together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this link [dependent dropdown using jquery ajax](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html)

How he maintained the relations among the entities

let me explain you if you want `countries` based on tour then you need to relate the `country table` with `tour table` as you have shown the `country table` in image it contains only two columns `countries_id`  and `countries_name` you have to add one more column  that is `tour_type_id` when you select any tour you will get the `tour_type_id` then your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM `countries`  where `tour_type_id` = 1 //this is the id you will get from the tour_type select box
```

and this will populate the related countries same case for the destination related this table with `country_id`

Hope it makes sense

Comment: This looks like a good tutorial. Something i am trying to achieve in the same way. I will have a look at this thanks

Comment: I just realized that all his data is on 1 table. But I have got 3 separate tables. I need all 3 tables to by dependent on each other.

Comment: Sorry, but i think i am still confused by this

Comment: Please refer to this updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938885/create-dynamic-drop-down-box/16939100?noredirect=1#16939100. I think this simplifies on what I am trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to sole this.. you can use use php with a page refresh and 2nd way use jQuery ajax to populate fields accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

as i am an asp.net developer i can suggest you put your 2nd and 3rd drop down in an update panel(ajax update panels) then in your 2nd drop down query make it like $sql=mysql_query("Select countries_id,countries_name from countries where tour_type_id="+element_11.SelectedItem.Value+""); it will select those values whose tour_type_id is same as you selected in first drop down, same logic can be use in 3rd drop down as well