# take another table value for dropdown

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, while-loop

I have a while loop that display data from table student and an extra column that displays a drop down selection from employee table id which when selected, updates the id in student table. I have the following codes but on displaying it shows only 1 data from the employer table each line.

Here is the while loop. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) && ($row1 =mysql_fetch_array($search_result2))){
echo"<form action=manualallocation.php method=post>";
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stud_ID']."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stud_NAME']."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<Select name='ex1'>"."<option value='" .$row1['emp_id'] ."'>" .$row1['emp_id'] ."</option>"."</select>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='emp_location' value='" .$row1['emp_location'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='stud_FIELDOFSTUDY' value='" .$row['stud_FIELDOFSTUDY'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='student_yearCompleted' value='" .$row['student_yearCompleted'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name=hidden value=" . $row['stud_ID'] . ">";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='submit' value=update". "></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: Write form action='manualallocation.php'

Comment: Did it and nothing happens.. any other alt

Comment: Check all links I have given to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Replace `&&` with `and`. Check this [link](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.precedence) for documentation.

Watch out for the difference of priority between `'and vs &&'` or `'|| vs or'`:

```
<?php
$bool = true && false;
var_dump($bool); // false, that's expected

$bool = true and false;
var_dump($bool); // true, ouch!
?>
```

Because **'and/or' have lower priority than '=' but '||/&&' have higher**.

**2)** Use two different variable in while loop `$row1` and `$row2`. So first variable cannot overwrite second.

```
while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) and ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($search_result2)))
```

For your Dropdown, Check this links:-

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936649/dynamic-drop-down-box-from-mysql)

[Link2](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php)

**Warning**

> mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks it works partly. For the drop down how can i take data from the employer table and updates it in student table when i select it and press update?

Comment: @Oliver:  You are welcome :-) I am request you to ask this question as a new one .

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695599/get-the-selected-index-value-of-select-tag-in-php

Comment: When i copy paste the codes and change the values, it takes only 1 value from the table employer of emp_Name each lines. It does not give me the options on a single dropdown each line. Any idea why ?
Here is the extracted code
    echo "<td>" . "<select name=\"status\"><option value='" .$row1['emp_Name'] ."'>" .$row1['emp_Name'] ."</option></select>"."</td>";

Answer (score 0):

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result2))){
```

Here you rewrite your `$row` variable with the second statement. You should use different variables.

```
while(($row_stud = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) && ($row_emp = mysql_fetch_array($search_result2))){
```

And then when working with emp data use `$row_emp`

```
$row_emp['emp_id']
```

and when with students - `$row_stud`

```
$row_stud['stud_ID']
```