# Get data from database and put in SELECT TAG

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have three select tags (1)Category, (2)Sub-Category, (3)Product Description and I want to fill it with data from database. But what I want is to when I select eg. Office Supplies from the Category on the Sub Category will only display eg. Ballpen, Ruler, Notebook and when I select eg. Ballpen on the Product Description will only display the description of the Ballpen. Btw I had created some code made from PHP but it only fills the select tags. I hope someone will help me. This is for out Thesis. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Select</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(`product_cate`) FROM `tbl_product` ";
$result =  mysql_query($query);

?>

Category:
 <select id="select1">

 <option></option>
 <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$displayData = $data['product_cate'];
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $displayData;?>"><?php echo $displayData; ?></option>

 <?php } ?>
 </select>

 <?php

$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT(`product_sub`) FROM `tbl_product`";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
 ?>

 Sub Category:
 <select id="select2">

<option></option>
<?php while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $displayData2 = $data2['product_sub'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $displayData2;?>"><?php echo $displayData2;?></option>

<?php }?>
  </select>

  <?php 
$query3 = "SELECT DISTINCT(`product_desc`) FROM `tbl_product`";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
  ?>
  Product Description:
  <select id="select3">

<option></option>
<?php while($data3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    $displayData3 = $data3['product_desc'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $displayData3;?>"><?php echo $displayData3;?></option>

<?php }?>
  </select>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: why don't you just help me? Please. :)

Comment: I think you are trying to do something like this: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/ you might want to make use of jQuery to create a "chained" select/dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

General guide on the path to take would be to use jquery. Basically what will happen is that you'll load the first select ie Category. When the user selects a category, the change should fire up an ajax call to query the db and get sub directories from the category id posted. the call returns the sub category as json which you'll put in the select box. same plan for the product description

This can be a starting point and follow up from there:

[jQuery dropdown dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449547/jquery-dropdown-dependent)

Lots of similar questions here

Answer (score 0):

You can just link options with an other attribute for example :

```
<select class="cat"><option>Category<option><select>
<select class="sub_cat"><option data-cat="Category">Sub-Category<option><select>
```

after that use can use javascript to hide unwanted categories for example (with jquery) :

```
$('.cat').change(function() {
   $('.sub_cat option:not([data-cat="Category"])').hide();
});
```