# Pass data from dynamic select box with ajax to php without submit or reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to create two select boxes: One that gets it's options from a database and the other that gets it's options depending on the value of the first select box.

My current code is below (I got the value from the first box with an alert, but don't know how to get it in the sql query for the second box). My document name is tutorial.php and I'm not using any other files except for the database functions, which are in include/config.php.

I've followed dozens of tutorials and stack overflow answers, but I can't get it to work. How can I get the select values to the php code on the same page?

jquery:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $( "#shoot" ).change(function(){ 
    id_firstSelect = $("#shoot").val();
    loadSecondSelect(id_firstSelect);
});

function loadSecondSelect(first_id)
{
    $("#model").ready(function(e) 
    {
        $.get(
        route.php, //Filter your select
        params, // In this case your id
        function(result) 
        {
        $("#model").empty();
        $("#model").append('<option value="0">-- Select --</option>');
        if(result.response['id_second'].length) // this receive your data 
        {
            for(var i=0, len=result.response['id_2'].length; i<len; i++) 
            {
                $("#model").append('<option value="' + result.response['id_2'][i] + '">' + result.response['name_2'][i]+'</option>'); 
            }
        }                       
        },
        "json");
    });
}

});
</script>
```

form with php functions:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="paard" selected>Paarden</option>
        <option value="hond">Honden</option>
        <option value="mens">Mensen</option>
        <option value="eigen">Eigen werk</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file"/><p>

    Ophalen uit database shoots:
    <select name="shoot" id="shoot">
<?php
    $values = mysql_query("SELECT distinct name FROM shoots") or die(mysql_error());
    //$numrows = mysql_num_rows($values);
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($values)){
        echo "<option value='".$result['name']."'>".$result['name']."</option>";
    }
?>
    </select><p>

    <select name="model" id="model"></select>

    <label class="radio">Portfoliomateriaal</label>
    <input type="radio" name="folio" value="TRUE" /> <span>Ja</span>
    <input type="radio" name="folio" value="FALSE" checked /> <span>Nee</span><p>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any code to handle the ajax request.

Comment: Yeah, can't figure out how to do that. I have the ajax itself in my code, but I don't know how to handle it further..

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempt. This is more of a place to come when you're having a specific problem, getting a specific error, etc.

Comment: @PatrickQ: You should see my browser history concerning this issue.. Can't figure it out. Almost every example redirects to another php file, and I can't seem to figure out how to handle it by staying on the page. But that said, jquery/javascript isn't my strongest suit. At all. :) If you could give me a hint or push in the right direction? Basically I want to know how to get the value send by ajax in the php code at the second select box.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://www.infotuts.com/cascaded-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/). [Here's another one](http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html) (ignore the db connection stuff in that one though). [Here's a similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449547/jquery-dropdown-dependent)

Comment: Those examples redirect to a different page (well, not exactly redirect but I dont know how to say it differently).. When I try that code, I get in trouble when I do $shoot= $_GET['shoot'];, because there is nothing to use GET on..

Comment: There's a _reason_ why most (all?) of the examples use a different page to handle the ajax request. It is much cleaner to do it that way. Separating your PHP from your HTML will help you immensely, as having them jumbled together just gets confusing.

Comment: Yeah but won't it screw up my file upload? Since it's handeling on a different page. And the file upload shouldn't begin before the the right options are selected, for which it has to stay on the same page. Right?

Answer (score 0):

In the first select, you could call a function with the id of the select to filtrate the data of the second select like:

in the first select you could do this to fill the second with the first id:

```
$( "#id_firstSelect" ).change(function() 
{ 
    id_firstSelect = $("#id_firstSelect").val();
    loadSecondSelect(id_firstSelect);
}
```

and call the function to load the second select

```
function loadSecondSelect(first_id)
{
    $("#id_secondSelect").ready(function(e) 
    {
        $.get(
        route.php, //Filter your select
        params, // In this case your id
        function(result) 
        {
        $("#id_secondSelect").empty();
        $("#id_secondSelect").append('<option value="0">-- Select --</option>');
        if(result.response['id_second'].length) // this receive your data 
        {
            for(var i=0, len=result.response['id_2'].length; i<len; i++) 
            {
                $("#id_secondSelect").append('<option value="' + result.response['id_2'][i] + '">' + result.response['name_2'][i]+'</option>'); 
            }
        }                       
        },
        "json");
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be correct? It gives errors when I paste it in my file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check it again, and you could adapt to your needs and the id's

Comment: I've edited my post with the code I have now. Still not working,  it's not putting anything into the second select box.. Probably doing something wrong but I don't know what